# Reg Ex validation and extraction of text

Tags: c#, regex

I'm playing with a SMS service that allows customers to text us, part of the text they are sending will contain national insurance number, value and date.

So I need to be try and be as smart as possible dealing with formats.

For example if someone texts (in the format)

"QQ123456A 500 4/oct"
OR

"QQ123456A 500.00 24/oct"
OR

"QQ123456A 500.00 24/oct/14"
OR

"QQ123456A 500.00 24/10/14"
OR

"QQ123456A 500.00 24-oct-14"
OR

"QQ123456A 500.00 24oct14"

how do I go about extracting this and validating the format as much as possible, example would be great.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Sounds like you need to split the string by whitespace which would give you the insurance number, value, and date separately. Then you'd only need to parse a date, no regex required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pseudo code

Split by space

regex for NI number `^\s*([a-zA-Z]){2}\s*([0-9]){1}\s*([0-9]){1}\s*([0-9]){1}\s*([0-9]){1}\s*([0-9]){1}\s*([0-9]){1}\s*([a-zA-Z]){1}?$` (untested)

Number - I presume that is a payment so it can only really be a number, a decimal or a comma (5,000.00) maybe proceeded by a £ sign - so that is easy to test for.

Date - no quick way around it - I could probably do a couple of tests - does it contain - or /.

Does it contain oct, nov etc.

Depending on which test is passed - parse date accordingly.

You could just check that you have matched NI number and Cost - if you have then you could just literrally use `.format()` on the remaining value. (or whatever - been ages since used C# - just format to date - if it doesn't parse then return `false`.)

Then just run a check that no parts return false.

That should be fairly robust.